# Resetting overflow with jquery messing up font sizes

Tags: jquery, css, lightbox

I have made a simple lightbox like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".abc").click(function(event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           var href = $(this).attr("href");
           $(".bucket").load(href);
           $(".overlay").css({"display": "block"});
           $("body").css({"overflow": "hidden"});

       });
       $(".overlay, .close").on('click', function(e) {
           if( e.target !== this ) 
                return;
           $("body").css({"overflow": "visible"});
           $(this).hide(); 
       });
   });
```

As you can see I disable the bodies scrollbar by applieng overflow:hidden.

After the lightbox is closed I am resetting the overflow property back to normal.

Somehow everything is messed up after. All font-sizes seem to randomly change.

What could be the problem?

Here a demo:

Click the link which says "ABC" to see the effect:

http://www.deutsch-lernen.com/DLOneu/learn-german-online/beginners/uebung9_1.php#top

Comment: The HTML loaded with `$(".bucket").load(href)` includes a `<link>` to external CSS overriding your original styles.

Comment: Opps. Indeed it does. Thank you! 10x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your lightbox open I believe it is including alleSeiten.css and it is changing the anchor  and other style globally. Which is making it to change the font of the top menu and at other places.

Your default style for anchor tag is:-

> a:active{
>       color: inherit;
>       display: block;
>       font-size: 14px;
>       padding-top: 10px;
>       text-decoration: none;
>       text-transform: uppercase;
>       width: 100%; }

And for alleSeiten.css it is:-

> a {
>       color: #666666;
>       font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
>       font-size: 8pt;
>       font-style: normal;
>       font-weight: bold;
>       line-height: normal; }

You need to make changes to your alleSeiten.css so that it should not affect the page style. Eventually it is overriding your style.css styles.

Answer (score -1):

The way you use the css() method, you replace the whole css code for the selected element. Try the following to only change the specific css attribute (display/overflow):

Wrong:

```
$(".overlay").css({"display": "block"});
```

Correct:

```
$('.overlay').css('display', 'block');
```